# How to get Google Drive (Docs) search to work in Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, lenses, scopes

How to get Google Drive (Docs) search to work in Unity Dash?

I've added my Google account in the `Online Accounts` System Settings panel.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 with the following packages installed:

```
ii  unity-lens-applications
ii  unity-lens-files
un  unity-lens-friends
un  unity-lens-gdocs
un  unity-lens-music
un  unity-lens-photos
un  unity-lens-shopping
un  unity-lens-video

un  unity-scope-calculator
un  unity-scope-colourlovers
un  unity-scope-deviantart
un  unity-scope-gallica
un  unity-scope-gdocs
ii  unity-scope-gdrive
un  unity-scope-github
un  unity-scope-googlenews
un  unity-scope-imdb
un  unity-scope-launchpad
un  unity-scope-manpages
un  unity-scope-openclipart
un  unity-scope-openweathermap
un  unity-scope-soundcloud
un  unity-scope-virtualbox
un  unity-scope-yahoostock
un  unity-scope-yelp
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at my own installation, you can open the Dash, then click the 'files' lens and type in the name of your document that's on Google Drive. This works for me